# Can someone explain how this C snippet will be evaluated w.r.t sequence points?

Tags: c, expression

Is this Undefined Behavior under C? I say this because I think that the function `inc(int *k)` can be thought of as an expression whose side effect is to update the value at the address of `k`. So, would that make it equivalent to `i=i++`, which is UB?

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*Edited(See comments below on dbush's answer)*/
int inc(int *k) {return ++(*k);}
/*End of edit*/
int main() 
{
  int i=0;
  int *ptr = &i;
  i = inc(ptr);
  printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behavior is well defined because calling a function counts as a sequence point, and each statement within the function is also a sequence point.  It is **not** the same as if the body of the function were put in its place.

First `inc` is called.  This invokes a sequence point.

Within the function, the statement `return ++(*k)` is executed, which first evaluates the containing expression.  This results in `i` in `main` getting incremented to 1, and the expression evaluates to the new value of `i`, which is 1.  The `return` statement returns that value from the function, and the completion of that statement is another sequence point, so the side effect of incrementing `i` is guaranteed to be complete.

Back in `main`, the value of 1 returned from `inc` is then assigned to `i`.

Had you instead done this:

```
i = ++(*ptr);
```

*That* would be undefined behavior because there is no sequence point between assigning to `i` and the side effect of incrementing `i` via `*ptr`.

Comment: The sequence point for calling the function is before the evaluation of the function body and does not sequence expressions in the function relative to the assignment side effect. C 2018 6.5.2.2 10: “There is a sequence point after the evaluations of the function designator and the actual arguments but before the actual call. Every evaluation in the calling function (including other function calls) that is not otherwise specifically sequenced before or after the execution of the body of the called function is indeterminately sequenced with respect to the execution of the called function.”

Comment: However, that makes the side effects indeterminately sequenced rather than unsequenced, and indeterminate sequencing of side effects on a scalar object does not trigger the rule for undefined behavior, unlike unsequenced effects. And the assignment side effect is, by the semantics of assignment, sequenced after the value computation of the right side, which means the expressions in the function must precede the assignment, which means the sequence point at the end of the full expression in the function precedes the assignment, and the increment precedes that sequence point.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: There's also a sequence point when the function returns: the `return` statement has a sequence point at the end of it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: C 2018 6.8.6.4, which discusses `return` statements does not say there is a sequence point. 7.1.4 3 says there is a sequence point before standard library functions return, but that does not apply to non-library functions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: But there is a complete expression after the `return` and the end of that marks a sequence point, just as much as if there was an explicit statement about it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That sequence point is already mentioned in my earlier comments: “the sequence point at the end of the full expression in the function.”

Comment: Hi, I realize that I made a mistake in my inc function. I wanted to have a function which increments the value at the address. I am adding an edit.
I think that the statement " calling a function counts as a sequence point" still explains that. I am still a little bit confused though. Can a function evaluation be thought of as an expression and if so, am I right in assuming that the side-effect is updating the pointer value in this example? If this is a correct, I interpret your statement to mean that the location pointed to is guaranteed to be updated when the function returns.

Comment: @abjoshi I figured as much regarding the increment.  I updated the answer to reflect the modified question.  As for the function evaluation, the actual function call is a sequence point, although if an expression contains multiple function calls then the order in which they are called is not specified. There is however a sequence point after every statement in a function, so the side effect of the increment is guaranteed to be complete by the time the function returns.

Comment: @dbush , based on what you said, the value of d here is undefined?


        i = d=inc(ptr) + inc(ptr);
        printf("%d, %d\n", d, d++);

Comment: @abjoshi The `d=inc(ptr) + inc(ptr)` part is not undefined but unspecified, since you don't know which `inc` gets called first but there are still sequence points between reads and writes.  On the other hand `printf("%d, %d\n", d, d++);` is undefined behavior because `d` is read and written without a sequence point.